# Understanding the symbols in scheme

Tags: scheme

Can you help me understand why there are 7 symbols (including duplicates) in the value of the following expression ?

```
​'('a ',(string->symbol "b") 'c))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that checks whether elements are symbols.
Pair the element with its "symbolness" for clarity:

```
(define (sym-check ls)
  (cond ((null? ls) '())
        ((not (pair? ls)) (cons ls (symbol? ls)))
        ((pair? (car ls)) (cons (map sym-check (car ls)) (sym-check (cdr ls))))
        (else (cons (sym-check (car ls)) (sym-check (cdr ls))))))

> (sym-check '('a ',(string->symbol "b") 'c))
'(((quote . #t) (a . #t)) ((quote . #t) 
                           ((unquote . #t) 
                            ((string->symbol . #t) ("b" . #f)))) 
                          ((quote . #t) (c . #t)))
```

and you get seven `#t`s.
Note that`'` and `,` are "shorthand" for the symbols `quote` and `unquote`,

```
> (quote (unquote (string->symbol "b")))
',(string->symbol "b")
```

and that using `list` instead of quoting gives a very different result:

```
> (sym-check (list 'a ',(string->symbol "b") 'c))
'((a . #t) ((unquote . #t) ((string->symbol . #t) ("b" . #f))) (c . #t))
```

which is the same as leaving quoting out of the quoted list:

```
> (sym-check '(a ,(string->symbol "b") c))
'((a . #t) ((unquote . #t) ((string->symbol . #t) ("b" . #f))) (c . #t))
```

Answer (score 1):

​`'('a ',(string->symbol "b") 'c))` evaluates to the following structure:

```
((quote a) 
 (quote (unquote (string->symbol "b"))) 
 (quote c))
```

I can count 7 so yes. It is 7 symbols in the result of evaluating the quoted expression.

Scheme system has a reader that translates `'x` to `(quote x)` and  `,`, `` ` ``, and `,@` corresponds to forms with `quasiquote`, `unquote`, and `unquote-splicing`. That means that the code `` `(a b c ,d e f) `` becomes `(quasiquote (a b c (unquote d) e f))`. Then the macos in the implementation translates it into `(list* 'a 'b 'c d '(e f))` or a similar expression that does the same. However with `` '`(a b c ,d e f) `` just becomes the value `(quasiquote (a b c (unquote d) e f))` since that is the expression that was quoted. Scheme doesn't expand into normal quote expression.

Usually quote characters inside quoted datum is a bug. Beginners doesn't understand the purpose and thin it needs to be everywhere. But really you only need the outer quote. `(+ 4 5)` is `9` and `'(+ 4 5)` is `(+ 4 5)`. See the difference?